# Major iOS9 performance issues with Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, performance, sprite-kit, ios9, xcode7

I am experiencing HUGE performance issues with iOS9 and I just can't figure out what to do. I've read many posts - [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14487), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706105/spritekit-ios9-fps-drop) for example, but their suggested solutions don't help or make little difference.

My game has gone from 60fps on an old iPad 2 (iOS 8.4) to < 15fps on a new iPad mini (iOS 9).

I'm trying to work out the main culprit. I'm pretty certain one of them is SKCropNodes. I usually render several SKCropNodes in my scene (6 - 18). This was never an issue in iOS8, but it appears iOS9, while it does a better job of cropping, also eats up performance doing so.

If I render the crop nodes as normal SKSpriteNodes, I gain maybe 5fps on old devices, and up to 30 on a newer iPhone 6. I have no alternative to using crop nodes, but it can't be the whole problem.

I thought perhaps the wrong texture atlas was being used - i.e. one of a much larger resolution. However forcing my device to use a very small atlas made no difference.

I'm using Texture Packer to generate my atlases with scaling variants for the different devices. I've noticed XCAssets now features an option to add a Sprite Atlas (I can't seem to find any documentation about this). This isn't suitable to my game, since I use 100s of sprites. I've tried adding my atlases to XCAssets, but then for some reason it won't use the scaling variants. Nevertheless, with low res textures, it still runs terribly.

I have tried setting

```
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
```

and given all my nodes zPosition values, but still no effect. I have also added the .png extension to every image name (originally a problem that meant they wouldn't render.)

I have some SKEffectNodes in my scenes, but removing and adding these doesn't seem to have an effect.

I don't understand how the same hardware and the same code can produce such drastically different results. Obviously Apple has changed something to do with rendering that has had an adverse effect. They also seem to have no intention of fixing these issues. I am aware of bugs on the issue that have been there for months - long before iOS9 was released.

I've been working on this game for 2 years now, and only just released it before iOS9. It's now suffering from terrible performance, and regular crashes.

Has anyone figured out what exactly Apple did to kill performance? If I knew that, I could at least try to work around it... Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Below are some figures for the same scene, with the absolute maximum number of nodes the game would generate at one time.

iOS 8, iPad 2, ~200 nodes, ~100 draws, 58.7 - 60 fps

iOS 9, iPhone6, ~280 nodes, ~216 draws, around 20 fps

I assume the difference in number of nodes is due to the different screen sizes. If I change the scene on iPhone 6 to achieve equivalent values, the FPS is still around 24.

**UPDATE 2**

Using Xcode's template Sprite Kit project, and changing the spaceship to an SKCropNode containing the spaceship, on iOS 8 I am able to add 100s of ships with no frame rate issue. On iOS 9, same project, I can add about 25 before the frame rate drops to < 30.

iOS 8 on iPad2:

[image]

iOS 9 iPhone 5:

[image]

In terms of texture atlas use, as in my comment, I can't guarantee that anything will be drawn from the same atlas. My game contains customised characters, with assets from a range of atlases (each of which contains ~100 textures). There can be up to 9 characters on screen at a time. I understand this isn't the most efficient in terms of draws, but I've never had a problem until iOS9...

**Update 3**

I've submitted a bug to Apple, including my sample program. I also used up one of my tech support requests. So far, nothing from Apple.

Comment: Please update your question with relevant performance information such as: Number of draw calls and FPS on 8 vs 9, Instruments time and fps profiles of 8 vs. 9, etc.

Comment: Ok, I've added some more info. Even on an iPhone 6 vs iPad 2 in the same scene, there is a massive performance hit.

Comment: @Smikey About draws count (unrelated to doubled draws issue) Even 100 draws are too much for 200 nodes. . First make sure that you are using atlases correctly. Read this for more info about what can break the batch process : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22856964/3402095. Second, you have to keep in mind that SKLabelNode, SKShapeNode and SKCropNode require (at least) one draw call per node. Those can't be drawn in batches like SKSpriteNode.

Comment: Hmm, but this wasn't a problem in iOS8, even with high draws? The nodes themselves draw instantly and it's only the frame rate that suffers once they're drawn. Re texture atlases, unfortunately I can't do much about that.  My scene contains characters which can be built from any combination of assets split over at least 2 texture atlases... So one character will be drawn from at least 2 atlases. But again, this was never a problem before...

Comment: @Smikey I am curious. The two photos you provided what do you get for draw calls? You should only be getting a few. If you already provided that for the two photos sorry for not seeing it. Also those screen grabs from actual devices?

Comment: Yes, they're from devices.. Not sure why the black boarder on the iPhone 6. Re draw calls - I'll have to run it again, and show them. Will update asap. I know I'm getting higher draw calls on iOS9 in other regular scenes...

Comment: Ok I've updated the screens, this time with draws included.

Comment: @Smikey Can you link to a download of the test project you are showing and submitted to Apple?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ajs0m64zdrdnt3r/AAB1oOuE2dpkh-n4qpOBb0Mpa?dl=0

Comment: @Smikey So I optimized what you had and got it down to two draw calls but it still went down to 40fps. What is even more odd is if you take the default game project and remove the SKAction it too drops down to 40fps when there is about 120 to 140 nodes on screen. Unfortunately I don't have a solution unless your background can be static after objects are added. (side note if you are responding to someone on SO you should @therename).

Comment: Thanks @SkylerLauren out of interest, what optimisations did you do to get it to 40fps? Hmm, it seems that the problem might not be related to SKCropNodes then, but just the overall SKNode count??

Comment: @Smikey So it seems. I went ahead and posted an answer based on my findings. Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the majority of iOS9 issues are addressed in the latest iOS9.2 beta & Xcode 7.2 beta.

Thank you Apple for *finally* addressing the problem. Too bad I spent 2 months working on work-arounds.

I've been posting on Apple's forums, submitting bugs and communicating with a support technician. It's a shame that at no point did Apple offer any clarity over what issues they were aware of, and what the Sprite Kit team were addressing.

Still, at least it seems the majority of Sprite Kit issues are now resolved, and a career change is no longer necessary :]

Comment: Do you know if this problem fix since iOS 7 or just since 8?

Comment: Early betas of 9.3 are showing some returns to the prior issues, and some new issues. All degrading performance of Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 13):

There are two main issues.

One is a radical drop in performance of Sprite Kit from iOS 8 to iOS 9 for all manner of reasons, some of which you've linked to, but there are others. It seems many aspects of rendering, sorting and storing/dealing with nodes is either broken or doubling or tripling their previous loads on CPU/GPU.

However there's another issue that further compounds efforts to resolve any of the possible performance problems. It's a pervasive and seemingly arbitrary frame rate capping mechanism that's most frequently noticeable when it operates at 40fps. But it also operates at other frequencies.

For many years this capping has been (rarely) noticed when folks manually use CADisplayLink to create game loops or other timing based mechanisms on a frame per frame basis.

With iOS 9 this seemingly automated capping has become a terribly unwanted "feature" of Sprite Kit, SceneKit, Metal and OpenGL ES based applications.

In the case of SceneKit this is most telling because the capping occurs regardless of rendering choice - Metal or OpenGL - and seemingly on all devices, including things like the new 6S phones and the iPad Air 2, even with very simple, default template projects.

"Renderer" is a line item in the detailed statistics of SceneKit, onscreen, on the device. It's the most telling indication of a capping process. It's not there when a game runs stably at 60fps.

When capped at 40fps, no matter the amount of time required to do other activities onscreen and in logic, this component will absorb all remaining time in the game loop needed to maintain a solid 40fps capping. It varies according to the time required for other actives, always forcing an apparent goal of the underlying OS to hold the frame-rate at 40fps.

This problem in conjunction with the issues regarding iOS 9 Sprite Kit performance mean that it may not currently be possible to resolve all your issues. It will be extremely difficult to ascertain when you're hitting one of these (seemingly) arbitrary fps caps versus having caused an actual problem.

Just as an aside, these caps are not limited to 40fps. I've noticed them at 30fps, 24fps, 20fps, 15fps, 12fps and 8fps.

Of course Apple has never conceded nor admitted to this capping mechanism within the OS, nor commented on when/how/why it's so heavily impacting game and rendering processes.

My theory, as expressed in this post ( [Inconsistent SceneKit framerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821033/inconsistent-scenekit-framerate) ), is that it's part of iOS designed to facilitate the use of variable frame rate technology soon to come in the iPad Pro, and possibly in other devices.

It would make sense that 120Hz become a base rate for future devices, particularly given the focus on performance advantages of iOS, the new Apple TV and 240Hz sampling of the screen touches/pen within the iPad Pro... and the considerable number of 120Hz televisions in the market.

Even without variable frame rate technology (say... your TV), 120Hz display rates means 24fps movies can be played back at a stable 5:5:5 pattern of frame display --  this massively increases the joy/immersion when watching films, just about all of which are shot at and truly exploit the advantages of a true 24fps for blur and motion effects.

120Hz with either variable frame rate technology or 5:5:5 frame display will also save Apple enormous effort in terms of compression and decompression of films when compared to the pulldown methods currently used on all devices with a maximum frame rate of 60fps.

All speculation, but I'd guess the use of these frame rate cappings in game engine technologies are there to help make games use less power, too, and give (in the future) developers an option to framerate lock their games in a variable frame rate device world. It's very unfortunate that (if this is the case) they have done such a poor job or sorting out the capping issues in the OS and the nature of Sprite Kit, leading to a scenario where you're fighting blindly to get good, high, consistent frame rates.

Apple silence and seemingly uncaring attitude towards the problems these two sets of issues are causing is (quite possibly) a very strong indication of how they feel about "their game development community".

And it's the greatest single problem of dealing with the kinds of cutting edge and performance critical development problems inherent to game making within a closed source framework from a needlessly secretive and uncommunicative (almost belligerent) organisation.

Comment: Well this is the most comprehensive amount of information I've read on the issue yet. Unfortunately it confounds my worst fears - that Apple have done this intentionally, without regard for game devs, and is therefore unlikely to fix it. I'll try to minimise use of the update loop to see if that helps. At this point, I'd be happy with 40fps. Thank you for the information though, helps to know a bit more about what's going on, even if there doesn't appear to be much I can do about it...

Comment: Sorry, there's no apparent solution in sight, and the lack of communication from Apple is astoundingly arrogant. Probably the first company to openly be dismissive of independent game developers for more than a generation.

Comment: I don't actually think my issue pertains to the frame rate lock. Rather, it's as you suggested at the start - iOS9 doubling or tripling CPU/GPU loads for some reason. Having updated to 9.1 on my iPad2, my game crashes trying to open scenes that previously ran at 60fps on iOS8. I'll likely have to take it off the App Store now... I wonder if Apple did this on purpose to encourage users to upgrade to new hardware :/

Comment: I don't think it's got anything to do with hardware, as even the top of the line hardware has the same huge performance problems you're having on an iPad 2. There's some charts somewhere showing that it's a massive degradation in performance across all hardware from iOS 8 to 9.

Comment: As to the 40fps (and other rates) capping, you'll come across them anyways... because they're innate to the game engine/renderers and their use of CADisplayLink for timing. It's just harder for you to see them because you have so many other issues with performance thanks to iOS 9. If you start playing with simple projects you'll notice the frame rate caps in isolation.

Comment: Which is the point I'm trying to make: - these two problems MASSIVELY compound each other, because it will be nearly impossible for you to accurately determine when you're solving your problems with iOS 9 versus hitting these (seemingly arbitrary) frame rate caps.

Comment: The fact that there's not much outrage at these problems indicates the lack of users of Sprite Kit (and Scene Kit) and the lack of response from Apple educates about their opinions of users.

Comment: You can still see remnants of these frame rate capping mechanisms in iOS 10, on the device. You'll see it drop to 30fps, and even 1fps if it can, when nothing is moving. Whatever they're doing works better, but it still takes some time to ramp up to 60fps when it's slowed down to save battery life.

Answer (score 5):

In the example you provided I can see one way to improve the draw count and to validate that the crop node isn't the problem. I don't know how practical this is in your actual game, but this drastically limits your draw calls.

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene ()

@property(nonatomic, strong)SKTexture *spaceshipTexture;
@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

    myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 45;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:myLabel];

    //Create one texture to be used over an over
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    sprite.xScale = 0.5;
    sprite.yScale = 0.5;

    SKCropNode *cropNode = [[SKCropNode alloc] init];
    SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    mask.position = sprite.position;
    [cropNode setMaskNode:mask];
    [cropNode addChild:sprite];
    [self addChild:cropNode];

    //temp add to scene to create the texture than remove
    //keep pointer to texture so it can be reused
    self.spaceshipTexture = [self.view textureFromNode:cropNode];
    [cropNode removeFromParent];

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        //re use texture
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:self.spaceshipTexture];
        sprite.position = location;
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
}

@end
```

The downside is that the issue remains when you get up to 120+ ish nodes on screen.

Also note I created a fresh SpriteKit app using the default template and removed the SKAction. Unfortunately even the default Apple template suffers huge fps drops when you get up to 120+ nodes. So I don't know if there will be an answer and your best course of action is to file a bug report because I believe it should (and use to be able to) handle that many on screen without a drop in fps.

Also something worth noting this error comes up on the default project which could be related...

```
2015-10-20 10:46:50.640 Test[2218:658384] <CAMetalLayer: 0x15fe987c0>: calling -display has no effect.
```

**Update**
Doing a little more research I ran into this...

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14487

Looks like others are filing bugs for this...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I have tried textureFromNode, but unfortunately it's no use in my game, and as you noticed, doesn't seem to improve the situation much anyway. Also, that thread you linked to contains my own posts about the issue. I've also submitted a bug to Apple and used up a TIS request. They're 'looking in to it', but no word from the Sprite Kit team itself, just the guy assigned to my case...

Answer (score 1):

Lots of draws... Have you tried this?

```
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SKLightNode? If so try removing all light node's from your code. I did this and my game is running back at 60fps like it did in iOS8.

Source:[SKLightNode performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320450/sklightnode-performance-issues)